# mapping arraylist to iterator

Tags: struts2

How to map an String arraylist to iterator tag in struts 2

for er: public ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList;

this list1 have to be displayed in jsp using s:iterator give me the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the tag reference?

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/iterator.html

Answer (score 0):

```
do something like this: 

<s:iterator value="list1">
     <s:property/>
</s:iterator>
```

before posting any question like this do your hand-full exercise first